# libs versions when cross compiling

Tags: apt, 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit

I'm trying to build an application. It requires the next libs:
libev(x86-32) libev(x86-64) libev-devel(x86-32) libev-devel(x86-64)
for Ubuntu I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libev-dev
```

and get libev4 and libev-dev. But if I run

```
sudo apt-get install libev-dev:i386
```

it wants to remove old libev. I need all these libraries to compile versions for different platforms. How to install them all?

Comment: I think the package is not large in size. So, maybe you can download the i386 version, remove the old one, compile for whatever platform you want to do that for, and then again download the old one, whenever you need to compile for some other platform that needs the old libs.

Comment: I suggest you build in a chroot, although this link has other options - http://askubuntu.com/questions/130318/how-do-i-cross-compile-my-application-for-ubuntu-12-04-armhf-architecture-on-a-u

Comment: Which application? The libraries can't normally be installed from both architectures.